# counting numbers in mysql - codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, model-view-controller

[image]

How to find the number of occurances of open_id_fk in this table. I am using the below code in my model.

```
 $this->db->select('open_id_fk, COUNT(open_id_fk) as total');
 $this->db->group_by('open_id_fk'); 
 $this->db->order_by('total', 'desc'); 
 $query = $this->db->get('voting_ip', 10);
 return $query;
```

I am not getting proper output. the output is:

```
116 6
118 3
119 2
```

HTML

```
 <div id="openletter" style="color:black;font-family:'Lato',sans-serif;"> <br>
 <?php echo "<br><br>".$row->open_id_fk;?><?php echo $row->total; ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "number of occurances" ? You want the sum ? or just the number 4 ? (4 rows)

Comment: Did you try `$this->db->select('open_id_fk, COUNT(DISTINCT open_id_fk) as total');`

Comment: Then what is your expected output. And also define whats wrong with this output

Comment: output should be: 116 - 2
118- 1
119 -1